# Parse JSON string into an array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse a string from JSON and turn those elements into an array in Javascript. Here's the code.

```
      var data = "{"fname":"Todd","lname":"James","cascade":"tjames","loc":"res","place":"home", "day0":"0,1,2,3,"}";
      var getDay = data.day0;
      var getDayArray = getDay.split(",");
```

Essentially, I'm trying to get day0, which is 0,1,2,3, and turn it into an array with a structure of

```
[0] = 0
[1] = 1
[2] = 2
[3] = 3
```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: `var data = '{"...."}';data=JSON.parse(data);`, etc?

Comment: First, your object markup is invalid.  Second, what have you tried?

Comment: Wait... you changed your code and now there's no JSON

Comment: I'm not sure what you're hinting at here. I'm trying to take the day0 element out of JSON and put the numbers into an array.

Comment: Sorry, that was me; at first I thought it was a typo and I tried to correct it, but then I realized OP might actually have really screwy JSON code.

Comment: the variable data get echo'd from php, I just tried to recreate it here, sorry for the object markup issue. I've tried using CSVtoArray, but that didn't work out too well (didn't)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this. Is that trailing comma intentional?

```
var getDayArray = JSON.parse(data).day0.split(",")
```

Comment: You missed the `','` in `split()`

Comment: Crap, for some reason my brain thought the ',' was the default

Answer (score 1):

This is built into most modern browser JavaScript engines. Depending on what environment you are targeting you can simply do:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
day0 = data.day0.split(",");
```

It's pretty simple. If you are targeting environments that don't have access to a built in JSON object you should try [this JSON project](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers have support for [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). You would use it thusly:

```
  var dataJSON = '{"fname":"Todd","lname":"James","cascade":"tjames","loc":"res","place":"home", "day0":"0,1,2,3"}'; // You need to remove the trailing comma
  var data = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
  var getDay = data.day0;
  var getDayArray = getDay.split(",");
```

However, it might be better to modify whatever is generating the value for dataJSON, to return

```
  var dataJSON = '{"fname":"Todd","lname":"James","cascade":"tjames","loc":"res","place":"home", "day0":[0,1,2,3]}';
```