# How would I create an array from this string in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string that looks like this

```
[
    {"last_name":"Aiken","first_name":"George","state":"VT","party":"R"},
    {"last_name":"Allott","first_name":"Gordon","state":"CO","party":"R"},
    {"last_name":"Anderson","first_name":"Clinton","state":"NM","party":"L"},    
    {"last_name":"Bartlett","first_name":"Edward","state":"AK","party":"D"}
]
```

That is stored in a variable.
How would I add this string to an array so that I can then access the data (no punctuation)
is needed.

Comment: You may want to look up this thing called **JSON**

Comment: This is coming from a json file that has been parsed. I need to create an array with this data. Not sure how.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: In which form/order do you want to store data in array? Means key and values in two different arrays or something else?

Comment: Check out google.  It's really helpful for questions like this...

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6402115/778118)...

Comment: [GSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSON) can be useful for conversion of json to java object

Comment: && And then some. There's probably 1000 duplicates at this point.

Comment: This is for a class. We are using Blue Jay, and we using java's standard libraries, so I am not sure if that would work or not. – user1787331 1 min ago edit

Comment: Well... if you can't use libraries your teacher probably wants you to do it on your own.  Is there a policy in the class about begging for help online without putting in any effort on your own?

Comment: This is only one part of the program I am working on. I am asking on here because this is place to ask questions? I am not asking you or anyone else to write this program for me. Please and Thank you.

Comment: @user1787331 - "How do I do X" is not a valid question on StackOverflow. Ignoring that, there's literally hundreds of questions and answers already on SO that answer this. Use the search. Use Google. The answer is: Use a JSON parser, or write your own - details for the format can be found at http://json.org . I *highly* suggest the former.

Comment: @BrianRoach Most answers to this question use parsers that I cannot use in bluejay. This is why I asked. I have looked for a solution but was unable to find one. If you would be kind enough to point me to the 1 of the "hundreds" of solutions to what I am asking that would be great.

Comment: @user1787331 - If your answer to these comments is "I can't use an industry standard JSON parser" ... then your questions is "How do I write a JSON parser?" which again, would not be a valid question for StackOverflow.  Please understand there's no malice involved here, this is simply far beyond the defined scope of this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461142/parse-json-string-into-an-array)

Comment: A quick look at the [_BlueJ website_](http://www.bluej.org/help/faq.html#use-library) suggests there is no reason you can't use an external library.  There's no way your professor expects you to write your own JSON parser if you're a first year student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you have mentioned is a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string.

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange
>   format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for
>   machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the
>   JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition -
>   December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language
>   independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of
>   the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript,
>   Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal
>   data-interchange language.

You should use a parser to parse the JSON string and fetch its elements. There are multiple JSON parser available on internet such as:

1. [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
2. [JSON Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)
3. [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: This is for a class. We are using Blue Jay, and we using java's standard libraries, so I am not sure if that would work or not.

Comment: [This is the most basic JSON library](http://json.org/java/) for parsing JSON.  It's open source, so if you're not allowed to use libraries, you can look at the source code and do something similar (or identical) on your own.

Comment: @user1787331 Writing a JSON parser will be an entire project in itself and there is no point re-inventing the wheel. If existing parsers solve your purpose then try to leverage the use of them.

Answer (score 0):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> 1. A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>      list, or associative array.
> 2. An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.
>      ---> source & more info: http://www.json.org/

You just need to parse json object and iterate through json array to store the values in array.
These links may be helpful to you:

[Link 1 to parse json](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/04/convert-json-array-to-string-array-list-java-from.html)

[Link 2 to parse json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java)

[Link 3 to parse json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java)